# Rock Paper Scissors (C++)

Tags: c++

I have an assignment in college in C++ and it asks me to make a program for Rock Paper Scissors and it has very specific instructions. I have to create a struct (Player)that has these variables 
a) an character array (name[41])
b)an integer variable named points
c)a boolean variable named master
d) a character array (weapon[8]) that can take only the values rock, paper,  scissors.

1. I have to create a void function (checkMastery) that takes as an argument a pointer of a Player struct. In the function if the points of the player are less than 100, the player.master has to be set to false and if the points are equal or more than a 100 it has to be set as true.
2. I have to create another void function letsFight that takes as arguments pointers of two Player structs. In the function, if a player wins the battle in rock paper scissors, the points of that player are increased by 1 point, if a player loses the points are decreased by 1 and if it's a tie the points of both players are increased by 1. If any player, has something else as a weapon, the points of that player are set to 0 and the game ends.
3. I have to create a string function showBestPlayer that takes as arguments pointers of a Player structs. It checks who won by comparing the points of the players and prints its name and if we have a tie it prints tie.

Well I created the program bellow and it compiles. However, whatever it takes as input, the output is "tie". What can I do?

```
    //7540
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

struct Player {
    char name[41];
    int points;
    bool master;
    char weapon[9];
}players[2], *pointer1, *pointer2;

void checkMastery(Player *pointer);
void letsFight(Player *pointer1,Player *pointer2);
string showBestPlayer(Player* pointer1, Player* pointer2);
int main(){
    pointer1 = players;
    pointer2 = &players[1];
    cout<<"Enter the player's name:\n";
    cin>>players[0].name;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Enter the player's weapon:\n";
    cin>>players[0].weapon;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Enter the player's name:\n";
    cin>>players[1].name;
    cout<<"Enter the player's weapon:\n";
    cin>>players[1].weapon;
    fflush(stdin);
    checkMastery(pointer1);
    checkMastery(pointer2);
    letsFight(pointer1, pointer2);
    showBestPlayer(pointer1, pointer2);
}
void checkMastery(Player* pointer){
    pointer->master=((pointer->points<100) ? false : true); 
}
void letsFight(Player* pointer1, Player* pointer2){
    if (((*pointer2).weapon !="rock")&&((*pointer2).weapon != "paper")&&((*pointer2).weapon!= "scissors")) {
            (*pointer2).points = 0 ;
            if (((*pointer1).weapon !="rock")&&((*pointer1).weapon != "paper")&&((*pointer1).weapon!= "scissors")){
                (*pointer1).points = 0;
        }
    }
    if ((*pointer1).weapon == "rock"){
        if ((*pointer2).weapon == "rock"){
            (*pointer1).points+=1;
            (*pointer2).points+=1;
        }else if((*pointer2).weapon == "paper"){
            (*pointer1).points-=1;
            (*pointer2).points+=1;
        }else if((*pointer2).weapon == "scissors"){
            (*pointer1).points+=1;
            (*pointer2).points-=1;
    }else if ((*pointer1).weapon == "paper"){
        if ((*pointer2).weapon == "rock"){
            (*pointer1).points+=1;
            (*pointer2).points-=1;
        }else if ((*pointer2).weapon == "paper"){
            (*pointer1).points+=1;
            (*pointer2).points-=1;
        }else if ((*pointer2).weapon == "scissors"){
            (*pointer1).points-=1;
            (*pointer2).points+=1;
        }
    }else if((*pointer1).weapon == "scissors"){
        if((*pointer2).weapon == "rock"){
            (*pointer1).points+=1;
            (*pointer2).points-=1;
        }else if((*pointer2).weapon == "paper"){
            (*pointer1).points-=1;
            (*pointer2).points+=1;
        }else if ((*pointer2).weapon == "scissors"){
            (*pointer1).points+=1;
            (*pointer2).points+=1;
        }
    }
    }   
}

string showBestPlayer(Player* pointer1, Player* pointer2){
    if ((*pointer1).points > (*pointer2).points) {
        char bestPlayer[41];
        memcpy(bestPlayer,(*pointer1).name,40);
        cout << (*bestPlayer);
    }
    else if ((*pointer2).points > (*pointer1).points) {
        char bestPlayer[41];
        memcpy(bestPlayer, (*pointer2).name,40);
        cout << (*bestPlayer);
    }
    else if((*pointer1).points == (*pointer2).points) {
        cout << "tie";
    }
}
```

Comment: Code etc, in the question, please, not via links:)

Comment: Include the code and the exact error message (including the line it occurs at) in your question.

Comment: ..and exact error message copypasta.

Comment: Line 19  [Error] variable or field 'checkMastery' declared void

Answer (score 2):

You have a *lot* of compilation errors:

```
main.cpp:17:1: error: 'pointer' does not name a type
 pointer = players[2];
 ^~~~~~~
```

That's because you have

```
struct Player *pointer;

pointer = players[2];
```

This is at global scope; you can't put an assignment like that outside of a function (loosely speaker).  You could instead write:

```
struct Player *pointer = players[2];
```

But do note `players[2]` is past the end of the `players` array - it would be safe to compare with another pointer that had been incremented through `players` to determine if you were at the end of the array, but can not be safely dereferenced.  You might want to assign to `&players[0]` (or - same but simpler notation - `players` - I haven't looked at how you later use `pointer` to know what makes sense.

```
main.cpp:19:26: error: variable or field 'checkMastery' declared void
 void checkMastery(pointer) {
                          ^
```

Saying "pointer" there doesn't make sense.  `pointer` is a global variable, but you're putting it into a function signature where a list of argument types and identifiers is expected.  Looking at your function body, there's no obvious use for an argument, as the function modifies global variables.

And on it goes...

```
main.cpp:25:16: error: variable or field 'letsFight' declared void
 void letsFight(struct* players[0], struct* players[1]) {
                ^~~~~~
main.cpp:25:16: error: expected primary-expression before 'struct'
main.cpp:25:36: error: expected primary-expression before 'struct'
 void letsFight(struct* players[0], struct* players[1]) {
                                    ^~~~~~
main.cpp:83:23: error: expected primary-expression before 'struct'
 string showBestPlayer(struct* players[0], struct* players[1]) {
                       ^~~~~~
main.cpp:83:43: error: expected primary-expression before 'struct'
 string showBestPlayer(struct* players[0], struct* players[1]) {
                                           ^~~~~~
main.cpp:83:63: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
 string showBestPlayer(struct* players[0], struct* players[1]) {
                                                               ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:98:20: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
  for (int i = 0; i = 1; ++i) {
                  ~~^~~
main.cpp:101:4: error: expected ';' before 'cout'
    cout << "Input a weapon:";
    ^~~~
main.cpp:104:12: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'Player')
  letsFight(*players[0], *players[1]);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:104:25: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'Player')
  letsFight(*players[0], *players[1]);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:104:2: error: 'letsFight' was not declared in this scope
  letsFight(*players[0], *players[1]);
  ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:105:17: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'Player')
  showBestPlayer(*players[0], *players[1]);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:105:30: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'Player')
  showBestPlayer(*players[0], *players[1]);
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

You basically need to work through each compilation error systematically - if you get it down to one or two you just can't understand *then* ask for help.  If you're totally overwhelmed, start with a tiny part of the problem, write code for that, make sure it compiles and works, and keep building things up gradually so you're in control as you go.

---

### Update

Ok, so you're still struggling.  Here's some code that doesn't crash.  Note I've avoided fixed-length arrays for things like `name` where you don't know how much data the user might type, and I've used *references* instead of pointers - it's much harder to get them wrong!  I haven't looked carefully at what the program is doing, but it shouldn't crash any more and you can hack it around until you're happy with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Player {
    std::string name;  // use std::string not char arrays
    int points;        // (much safer and easier)
    bool master;
    std::string weapon;
};

void checkMastery(Player& pointer);
void letsFight(Player& pointer1, Player& pointer2);
void showBestPlayer(Player& pointer1, Player& pointer2);

int main(){
    Player players[2]{};

    cout<<"Enter the player's name:\n";
    getline(cin, players[0].name);
    cout<<"Enter the player's weapon:\n";
    getline(cin, players[0].weapon);
    cout<<"Enter the player's name:\n";
    getline(cin, players[1].name);
    cout<<"Enter the player's weapon:\n";
    getline(cin, players[1].weapon);

    checkMastery(players[0]);
    checkMastery(players[1]);

    letsFight(players[0], players[1]);
    showBestPlayer(players[0], players[1]);
}

void checkMastery(Player& player){
    player.master = player.points >= 100;
}

void letsFight(Player& player1, Player& player2){
    if (player2.weapon != "rock" && player2.weapon != "paper" && player2.weapon != "scissors") {
        player2.points = 0;
        if (player1.weapon != "rock" && player1.weapon != "paper" && player1.weapon != "scissors") {
                player1.points = 0;
        }
    }

    if (player1.weapon == "rock"){
        if (player2.weapon == "rock"){
            player1.points+=1;
            player2.points+=1;
        }else if(player2.weapon == "paper"){
            player1.points-=1;
            player2.points+=1;
        }else if(player2.weapon == "scissors"){
            player1.points+=1;
            player2.points-=1;
    }else if (player1.weapon == "paper"){
        if (player2.weapon == "rock"){
            player1.points+=1;
            player2.points-=1;
        }else if (player2.weapon == "paper"){
            player1.points+=1;
            player2.points-=1;
        }else if (player2.weapon == "scissors"){
            player1.points-=1;
            player2.points+=1;
        }
    }else if(player1.weapon == "scissors"){
        if(player2.weapon == "rock"){
            player1.points+=1;
            player2.points-=1;
        }else if(player2.weapon == "paper"){
            player1.points-=1;
            player2.points+=1;
        }else if (player2.weapon == "scissors"){
            player1.points+=1;
            player2.points+=1;
        }
    }
    }   
}

void showBestPlayer(Player& player1, Player& player2){
    if (player1.points > player2.points) {
        cout << "best player: " << player1.name << '\n';
    }
    else if (player2.points > player1.points) {
        cout << "best player: " << player2.name << '\n';
    }
    else if(player1.points == player2.points) {
        cout << "tie\n";
    }
}
```

Specific problems your code had:

```
(*pointer1).weapon == "rock"
```

You can't just compare a character arrow to a string literal like `"rock"` - C++ will see if the character array is at the same address, and it *never* will be.  By using `std::string`, you can use `==` and it will work as expected.  With character arrays, you need to use the C-library function `strcmp(pointer1->weapon, "rock") == 0` to test for equality.

```
string showBestPlayer(Player* pointer1, Player* pointer2);
```

This promises that `showBestPlayer` will return a `string`, but your function just printed the best player on `cout` and returned nothing.  That may well have caused your crashes.

```
cin >> player1.name
```

When you use `>>` to stream in text, it stops when it finds whitespace, whether that's from the user typing ENTER or a space inside a name like "Jane Smith".  Then "Smith" will be accidentally read as Jane's weapon.

It's better to use `getline(std::cin, my_string_variable)`, as that will read everything through to the newline generated by ENTER, including spaces.

```
fflush(stdin);
```

There's never any need to flush `stdin`.  Any prompt written to standard output (sent via `std::cout`) should be flushed before reading from standard input so the user can see the prompt, but C++ does this automatically: the `std::cin` and `std::cout` streams are *tied* in that way.

Comment: I re-wrote the code and I have no compilation error, however when I run it, I get a segmentation fault. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Try an interactive debugger to work out which line is crashing.  For example, on Linux with GCC/GDB, `gdb myprogram` then in gdb `run`, then `bt` to see the call stack where it crashes.  Or, if you get a core dump, use a debugger to tell you which line it's from (`gdb myprogram core` / `bt`).

Comment: It didn't help at all. So I wrote it from scratch and now all I get is the same output and then a crash. I will change the code in the post so you can see it yourself

Comment: See code appended to answer....

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I still have to use pointers and char instead of string, because it is stated that I have to use these types in the assignment. However I really appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Well, it can work with pointers - just a bit clumsier.  By the way, `pointer1->name` is a shorthand notation for `(*pointer1).name` - just a little bit easier to type and read.  I think your crash was just showBestPlayer not returning the string it'd promised to, so you can keep the pointer and array stuff if you need to.  Do remember to use `strcmp(x, y) == 0` as I explained.  Cheers

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again

Comment: Oh - one final tip - if you're not sure where your program's crashing, you can always add `cout << __LINE__ << " I'm alive! x is " << x << '\n';` statements liberally throughout the code, seeing where in the code it was just before the crash.  (`cout << __LINE__` prints the line number in the C++ source code.)

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
pointer = players[2];
```

is only permitted within a function.   You have it at file scope (outside a function).   This gives the first error in your program (despite the fact you didn't mention it).

Since `pointer` is a variable, declared outside a function, the function definition

```
void checkMastery(pointer)   // rest of definition omitted
```

is invalid, since (in this context) pointer is required to be a type, not a variable.    Quick fix:  remove `pointer`.

The third problem is

```
void letsFight(struct* players[0], struct* players[1]) {
```

which tries to declare two arguments with the same names (`players`).  Since the function body attempts to use `players`, the quick fix is to change the above to

```
void letsFight(struct* players[]) {
```

That will probably trigger other diagnostics from the compiler - since your code declares `players` as a variable earlier on.

Rather than offer fixes for ALL the problems,

1)   When looking at error messages from a compiler the FIRST is the most important  (you are looking at the LAST).

2)   Read a basic textbook on C++, and learn about variables and types.  Work through basic exercises.   Trying to build code through GUESSWORK, such as you are, wastes your time and everyone else's.   And, yes, it is obvious you are guessing, given the way you've written the code, and posted the question.